# Copying content from my other websites

Tags: plugins, multisite, content

I am currently working in a website for my company to clean up and create new modules. In this company website we share news/alerts or updates on our industry or regarding to our company, we can assume this website as a group of companies website.

On the other hand, we have few more websites which are currently our company's subsidiaries websites and all has been built quite long time ago with different structures and themes.

So when ever we share any news/update or alert on our group website, if it is related to one of our subsidiary websites, we have to go on that particular website and share it on there too. Sometimes one general news has to be post on multiple sites and it takes long time and causes confusion like forgetting to add canonical links or missing links/images.

Does anyone has any idea how to automate posting among these websites?

It can be trusted plugin or dashboard that can link multisites together, like Wordpress multisites. I know wordpress multisites would not work me but I believe there is some platforms creates such environment for websites that does not share same theme. I am okay with premium plugin or platform.

Answer (score 0):

Use a syndication (feed) plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/syndicate-press/ in your subsidiary sites to pull in posts from the main site. You can target specific categories of post - so this would help you to pull in just the posts that would be relevant to the subsidiary site.

This will help visitors to the subsidiary sites see content relevant to them, but it will most likely not have a positive impact on the SEO for those subsidiary sites, as search engines will already have seen (and indexed) the content from the main site.

Comment: thanks for your opinion. I will look into syndicate press and yes you are right I am aware of how duplicate content causes bad reputation on SEO but we are already doing that so nothing much would change.